# My OpenCV Face Recognition isn't drawing a bounding box / recognizing a face

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I am making an OpenCV Face Recognizer that draws a bounding box around the faces it detects from an image it has read. I am using a cascade classifier (haarcascades)
It shows the picture, not in grayscale (full color) and will not draw the bounding boxes. Not sure what I did, I am new to this.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2

# Load image
image = cv2.imread("/home/tyler/Downloads/PythonProjects/VN5anAL3_400x400.jpg")

# Convert image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Define the cascade classifier
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# Detect faces
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(30, 30))

# Draw bounding boxes
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

# Show the image
cv2.imshow("faces", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What if remove minSize=(30, 30)?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, but you are drawing the bounding boxes on the grayscale image instead of the original image. Instead of using the `gray` variable, use the `image` variable in the following line to draw the bounding boxes:

```
cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
```

Also, you may want to check if the cascade classifier is loaded correctly by adding the following line before the detection:

```
if face_cascade.empty():
    raise Exception("Failed to load cascade classifier.")
```